# Custom STS with Windows Identity Foundation (.NET 4.5)

Tags: asp.net, security, single-sign-on, identity, wif

I need to implement a custom STS with Visual Studio 2012 with a login page for SSO (and SSOut) with different web applications (with different permissions, claims and .NET fxs, 3.5, 4.0 y 4.5). 
Can you help me to achieve this thing?
Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of examples available. I wrote one tutorial once:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web.html

It is worth to mention that while SSO is rather straightforward, you'll have to take care of the single sign-out also. And this is not-so-well documented. Here is how to do it:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/12/wif-ws-federation-and-single-sign-out.html

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/05/wif-ws-federation-and-single-sign-out.html

Note also that some people could probably vote to close your question as it is too broad. You should rather ask about specific issues.

Comment: Could you update that blog post to WIF (.NET 4.5) with Visual Studio 2012? It will be very useful.

Comment: I don't expect it to change much but to be frank - I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I need to change or take in account something to use an IP-STS with multiple RPs?

Comment: Nothing special just read my tutorial on single sign out. You wont have any issues with single sign on as it works out of the box with a sts.

Comment: WIF 4.5 is baked into .Net 4.5.  Objects have moved into different namespaces.  There are no out-of-the box project templates for a custom STS in Visual Studio 2012.  It is a bit of a different animal that before. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/03/15/windows-identity-foundation-in-the-net-framework-4-5-beta-tools-samples-claims-everywhere.aspx

Comment: There is an extremely simple example of a custom STS here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545413(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [Identity and Access Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e)? It has a number of samples.

Haven't tried it myself and there were problems with VS 2012 but that's apparently been fixed.

Comment: tried to install yesterday got an error ... uninstalled and reinstalled and it seems like the local one works. however i really dont think that that extension is suitable for any real usage. I think its more intended for giving a developer a nice quick way into seeing what its all about without having to figure out ADFS2 or ACS first